# ActiveRecord select records based on uniqueness of two attributes in combination

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

My table looks like this:

```
ID    |    Multiple    |    Itemlist_ID    |    Inventory_ID
----------------------------------------------------------------
1     |    1           |    1              |    1
2     |    1           |    1              |    2
3     |    1           |    1              |    3
4     |    1           |    4              |    2
5     |    1           |    4              |    3
6     |    2           |    4              |    2
7     |    2           |    4              |    3
```

How do I retrieve records with unique combo of `Multiple` and `Itemlist_ID`? For example below:

```
ID    |    Multiple    |    Itemlist_ID    |    Inventory_ID
----------------------------------------------------------------
1     |    1           |    1              |    1
4     |    1           |    4              |    2
6     |    2           |    4              |    2
```

Note, this is retrieving for a View where the Inventory_ID won't be shown, so I'm not concerned whether I get back records `[1,4,6]` or `[1,5,7]` or `[2,4,6]`. Using a `first` command is fine.

Comment: Is it important that you retrieve the first Inventory_ID in the results? You could use a GROUP BY (Multiple, Itemlist_ID) if not.

Comment: no, I don't care about inventory_ID so it doesn't matter which is retrieved. How do you mean use a GROUP BY? Example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a GROUP BY query in Activerecord using this syntax (replace `Model` with your class name):

```
Model.group('Multiple', 'Itemlist_ID').select('Multiple', 'Itemlist_ID')
```

This would retrieve all unique combinations of (Multiple, Itemlist_ID).

You could optionally add aggregate operations on columns other than the two grouped columns, such as SUM, AVG, COUNT, etc. For example, if you wanted to know how many records are in each group:

```
Model.group('Multiple', 'Itemlist_ID').select('Multiple', 'Itemlist_ID', 'COUNT(1) AS group_count')
```

This would add an attribute to the result called 'group_count' that would be the number of records contained in each group